# Issue with offset in loop cycle.Object required

Tags: excel, vba

i'm having an issue in my While cycle with an offset.

There's the code:

```
    Sub Voucher()

            Dim rangoCargo, rangoTAG, rangoTipo As Range
            Dim archivo As String
            Dim vFound As Boolean

            Dim subFldr As Object
            Dim subsubFldr As Object

            Worksheets("OC").Visible = True
            Worksheets("OC").Select

            Set rangoTAG = Range("B2")
            Set rangoCargo = Range("C2")
            Set rangoTipo = Range("E2")

            Dim fso As Object
            Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

            rutaAño = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2017"
            rutaFARFI = rutaAño & "\FAR_FI"
            rutaFARTA = rutaAño & "\FAR_TA"
            rutaFARTN = rutaAño & "\FAR_TN"
            rutaGOPMTI = rutaAño & "\GOPM_TI"

            rutaDocumentos = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\SGSCM\02_ORDENES_DE_COMPRA\"                                                             

            If Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\2017", vbDirectory) = "" Then 'This checks if a main folder exist, do the procedure, nothing special

                MsgBox "Please, Check if the [2017] Folder Exists"

            Else 'if it exists:

                Do While Not IsEmpty(rangoCargo) 'Starts the cycle

                    If rangoTipo = "C" Then 'If Letter Type is C it loops through a folder until it finds the "C" Like one.

                        rangoCargo = Left(rangoCargo, 6) 

                        For Each subFldr In CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemobject").GetFolder(rutaFARFI).Subfolders
                            For Each subsubFldr In CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemobject").GetFolder(subFldr).Subfolders
                                Debug.Print subsubFldr

                                vFound = False

                                If subsubFldr Like "*\" & rangoTipo & rangoTAG Then 'If it finds it, copy and move the file from another folder to it.

                                    vFound = True
                                    cFolder = subsubFldr.Path

                                    archivo = Dir(rutaDocumentos & "\" & rangoCargo & "\*.*")
                                    Do Until archivo = ""

                                        Call fso.copyFile(rutaDocumentos & "\" & rangoCargo & "\" & archivo, cFolder & "\" & archivo)
                                        archivo = Dir

                                    Loop

                                End If 'ends subsubFldr

                                If vFound = True Then
                                    Exit For
                                End If

                            Next subsubFldr

                            If vFound = True Then
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next subFldr

                    ElseIf rangoTipo = "P" Then

                        archivo = Dir(rutaDocumentos & "\" & rangoCargo & "\*.*")
                        Do Until archivo = ""

                            Call fso.copyFile(rutaDocumentos & "\" & rangoCargo & "\" & archivo, rutaFARFI & "\" & rangoTipo & "\" & rangoTAG & "\" & archivo)
                            archivo = Dir
                        Loop

                    End If

                    Set rangoTAG = rangoTAG.Offset(1, 0)
                    Set rangoTipo = rangoTipo.Offset(1, 0)
                    Set rangoCargo = rangoCargo.Offset(1, 0) 'THIS OFFSET HAS THE PROBLEM
                'When the command Set rangoCargo = rangoCargo.Offset(1, 0) executes it throws the next message: Run Time Error '424' object required

                Loop 'The cycle end when it founds ""

            End If 'End if the folder [2017] doesn't exists

        End Sub
```

[Excel Worksheet (OC)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFjDN.png)

Ok, here goes the problem:

I'm using a Cycle to loop between a Sheet that contains a string of a "Folder" in his cellValue, in this case **Document Like**. I've done a Left(rangoCargo, 6) to catch the exact number of chars equals to the folder that contains the files to copy them and later move them to the new folder.

As you can see in the Document Like Column the first value is "E-0001-997818". Theres a main folder that contains another sub folders, we will call the Main folder **OC**. From OC i must get a document and move it to the searched folder (I.E E-001), so, E-001 contains the documents that must be moved to a new folder but, the E-001 is called like that, and in the "Document Like" column they're called like that but a lot of extra numbers (i don't know why, the corporation give the excel file to me and i must work with it without modificating it). 
So i did a Left() to get the exactly string of the folder to locate them, and there's is the problem, i don't know how to fix the "It Requires an Object" error.
I'm almost sure that is because of the Offset, but i don't know how to fix it.

So, any help could be very useful.Thank you for your time guys.

Comment: Have you put a break point on the spot that it's having an issue to see if `rangoCargo` has a string in it for the left function to check?

Comment: Yes, i've already test it, it have "E-0001" without all the other numbers.

Comment: Where exactly is it breaking or having the issue?  Is it at the left function or somewhere else? OH sorry i found your comment where you said you are having the issue.

Comment: try setting `rangoCargo` to `Range("C3")` to see if it's the cell that's having the problem.  I'm not able to duplicate the issue.  Either somehow `rangoCargo` is loosing it's reference to the range by the time it gets to the end, or there is something wrong with `C3`.  You could also try passing the `rangoCargo.Adress` to a variable before setting it to the next cell down to see if it still hold the reverenced `C2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I've found your issue.

When you dimension variables like this;

```
Dim rangoCargo, rangoTAG, rangoTipo As Range
```

you would think that they are all of type `Range`, but this is false.  the first two will be of type `variant` because they are not declared as any type and the last will be the only variable declared as a `Range` type.

You should change your declarations to either of the following and then your code should work.

```
Dim rangoCargo As Range, rangoTAG As Range, rangoTipo As Range
```

or

```
Dim rangoCargo As Range
Dim rangoTAG As Range
Dim rangoTipo As Range
```

since rangoCargo was declared as a variant it doesn't know that it's a `Range` object hence the reason why you're getting the error.  The first time you set the variable to `Range("C2")` it is not actually setting the range but the value its self.  To test, immediately after the first time you set `rangoCargo` add this code and it should fail;

```
p = rangoCargo.Value
```

It will give you the same error. `Run-time error '424': Object required`

Hope that helps.  Remember if this fixes your issue to mark as answer. So others can see what to do to fix the issue if they come across it too.

Comment: Man, thank you so much! I never thought the answer could be so easy. I've done that kind of declaration in all the rest of my codes without any trouble.
If you can (and only if you want to) i would like to explain why that kind of things happens.
And again, R. Roe, thank you for your time !

Comment: I thought I did explain it because the variable didn't have an explicit declaration it assigns it the `variant` object type.  http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=339929&seqNum=2 has a very good definition of the variant type at the bottom of the web page.  Also, please remember to mark as answer.